# Form Using iFrame as target resubmits when revisiting the page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, iframe

I've created a form on my website using Google Forms, and through a couple of tutorials I've prevent the page from navigating to the Google Forms thank you page and instead using my own thank you page.

The way this has been done is using a hidden iframe as a target on the form and then the iFrame checks if the form has been submitted successfully before switching the window to my thank you page.

```
<iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe"
   style="display:none;" onload="if(submitted == true)
  {window.location='https://www.normadorothy.com/sample-thanks';}">
</iframe>
```

This works fine and submits the form before showing the thank you page, however if the user then clicks the back button, the form is submitted again.

I've tried `console.log(submitted)` which returns false so not sure why this is being submitted twice.

Just for clarity, the form code is:

```
<form id="sample-form" class="validate" action="google-url" method="post" target="hidden_iframe" onsubmit="return validate();">
```

The validate function checks all the fields, sets `submitted` to true and then submits the form.

Any help would be great, I've been banging my head against a wall with this!

Answer (score 0):

I would guess this is happening because the back button tries to take you back to the iFrame's last known state (which is the form POST URL) and not the "raw" state you expect. You could try writing the iFrame using JS on the parent page to work around this:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.onload = function() { if(submitted == true)  {window.location='https://www.normadorothy.com/sample-thanks';}};
iframe.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :) 

Just tried this but unfortunately didn't work!